# onclick event not working with the links in javascript

Tags: javascript, onclick

I am new 2 javascript i have created function that adds onclick event & calls a user function  to all my links in a page
but it not working properly help me to solve this

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  window.onload=function() {  
  var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
  for(var i = 0, i<links.length; i++) {
  links[i].onclick = function () {  
  var string = links[i].href; //href value
  var str = string;    
  var spl = string.split("/");   
    switch(spl[2])
    {

        case 'www.google.com':
        var str1 = "http://yahoo.com";
        links[i].target="_blank";
        links[i].href= str1;

        break;

        default:
        links[i].href= string;
    }  
    }

 } 
 }

 </script> 

<a href="http://www.google.com/" target="-blank">www.google.com</a></br>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working properly?" Is there an error? Does it do nothing?

Comment: you are using `elements[i]` in the onclick function, that will always be the last element, since the for loop will be finished when the onclick function is called. is that your error?

Comment: no error it is following  default href value not the function href value

Comment: It doesn't go into the function at all. Put an alert there and see for yourself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2 problems:

1) You have a syntax error in your for loop.  You need to use semicolons instead of commas

```
for (var i = 0, i < elements.length; i++) {
```

vs

```
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
```

2) The onclick callback is referencing i.  The problem is, that you are changing i during your loop, but you only make the onclick callback *later*, after your loop completes.  Hence the value of `i` is actually going to be `1`.  And that means `i` will be the same value for *every* single link you click.  So, if you had 5 links, `i` will be 6 for all of them (6 being the first breaking-value of your for loop)

The important thing to remember here is onclick is called later, and you're updating `i` before then.  To get around this problem, you can capture the value of `i` at the time you define the onclick function like so:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        (function(index){ 
            elements[index].onclick = function () {
            var string = elements[index].href; //href value
            var str = string;
            var spl = string.split("/");
            switch (spl[2]) {

            case 'www.google.com':
                var str1 = "http://yahoo.com";
                elements[index].target = "_blank";
                elements[index].href = str1;

                break;

            default:
                elements[index].href = string;
            }
        }
        })(i);

    }
}
```

Comment: You still have the syntax error of the comma in the for loop xD